# loop on Json data using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I want to loop on json data but selecting products, the difficulty lies in that the objects that I want to select follow a pattern product-*. I want to find a sort peace of code that allows something like below:

```
$.each(data.products, function(i, product) {
   console.log(product.products_name);
});
```

The actual data JSON is:

```
{
    "orders_id": "411",
    "customers_name": "Larez",
    "product-1": {
        "product_name": "Walt",
        "product_type": "Poster",
        "product_quantity": "100",
        "product_size": "1/4 Pliego",
        "product_price": "100.00"
    },
    "product-2": {
        "product_name": "Penny",
        "product_type": "Poster",
        "product_quantity": "15",
        "product_size": "1/4 Pliego",
        "product_price": "15.00"
    },
    "product-3": {
        "product_name": "Carol",
        "product_type": "Poster",
        "product_quantity": "50",
        "product_size": "1/4 Pliego",
        "product_price": "50.00"
    },
    "product-4": {
        "product_name": "Julia",
        "product_type": "Poster",
        "product_quantity": "100",
        "product_size": "1/4 Pliego",
        "product_price": "100.00"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the data you receive?  It would be much more straightforward to handle a list of products for the order rather than generic product-1, product-2, etc. Though I obviously don't know the specifics of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
var data = { /* your data */ };
var product,
    i = 1;
while(product = data['product-' + i++]) {
    console.log(product.products_name);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should increment `i` =P

Comment: Works for the above example, but would break if `product-i` is not consecutive (not criticizing the answer, just pointing out what could go wrong).

Comment: Thanks Mike, love you solution since it works without any libraries and to Steve point in this case the server makes incremental changes

Answer (score 2):

You could use library like underscore.js and do something like the following to get an array of the product keys.

```
r = /product-\d+/
product_keys = _.filter(_.keys(json), function(k) { return r.test(k) });
```

Which you can then iterate through directly with just the product keys

Comment: Good idea.  You should probably declare the regex outside the _.filter() though so you only create one instance of it instead of N.

Comment: agreed, this was just a quick example but you get the idea. i'll update the example